# guava's cacheloader load method with more args?

Tags: java, guava

When the CacheLoader loads something for my Key, I need to pass in some initialization information(basically, a property of what is created).

Unfortunately, the load method only takes a Key K.  I could overload the Key we use to have an extra field that is not used in the equals/hashcode but that seems a bit ugly.  is there another option such that I can pass information for construction or an ability to pass in a callback creation with the property info in my callback already?  basically, every time I read from cache, I would pass key and callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> an ability to pass in a callback creation with the property info in my callback already?

Are you looking for [`Cache.get(K, Callable<? extends V>)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#get(K,%20java.util.concurrent.Callable))?